# Elasticsearch search query with nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am working on a resume database on elasticsearch. there are nested fields. For example, there is a "skills" section. "skills" is a nested field containing "skill" and "years". I want to be able to do a query that returns a skill with a certain year. For example, I want to get resumes of people with 3 or more years of "python" experience.

I have successfully run a query that does the following:

It returns all the resumes that has "python as a skills.skill and 3 as a skills.year
This returns result where python is associated with 2 years or experience as long as some other field is associated with 3 years of experience.

```
GET /resumes/_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "skills.skill":   "python" }}, 
        { "match": { "skills.years": 3 }}  
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to sort the data where that 3 is more associated with python?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of [Nested DataType](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and corresponding to it you would need to make use of [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

What you have in current model appears to be [basic object model](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html).

I've mentioned sample mapping, sample documents, nested query and response below. This would give you what you are looking for.

### Mapping

```
PUT resumes
{
  "mappings": {
    "mydocs": {
      "properties": {
        "skills": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "skill": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "years": {
              "type": "integer"
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST resumes/mydocs/1
{
  "skills": [
    {
      "skill": "python",
      "years": 3
    },
    {
      "skill": "java",
      "years": 3
    }
    ]
}

POST resumes/mydocs/2
{
  "skills": [
    {
      "skill": "python",
      "years": 2
    },
    {
      "skill": "java",
      "years": 3
    }
    ]
}
```

### Query

```
POST resumes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skills",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "skills.skill": "python"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "skills.years": 3
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Query Response:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.6931472,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "resumes",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.6931472,
        "_source": {
          "skills": [
            {
              "skill": "python",
              "years": 3
            },
            {
              "skill": "java",
              "years": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that you only retrieve the document having id `1` in the above response. Also note that just for sake of simplicity I've made skills.skill as `keyword` type. You can change it to `text` depending on your use case.

Hope it helps!